Handling None Values in Payload for Cashfree API in Flask
I'm working on integrating Cashfree payments in my Flask web application. During the process, I encountered an issue where some fields in my payload contain None values, which seems to be causing problems with the API request.
Here's the relevant part of my Flask backend code:

import uuid
import json
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import requests
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask_cors import CORS
from urllib.parse import quote
import logging

load_dotenv()

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

CASHFREE_APP_ID = os.getenv('CASHFREE_APP_ID')
CASHFREE_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('CASHFREE_SECRET_KEY')
CASHFREE_API_URL = "https://sandbox.cashfree.com/pg/orders"

@app.route('/create_order', methods=['POST'])
def create_order():
    try:
        data = request.json
        logging.debug(f"Request data: {data}")

        order_id = data.get('order_id', str(uuid.uuid4()))
        order_amount = data.get('order_amount')
        order_currency = 'INR'
        customer_id = data.get('customer_id', 'default_customer_id')
        customer_name = data.get('customer_name', 'teerkhelo')
        customer_email = data.get('customer_email', 'teerkhelo@gmail.com')
        customer_phone = data.get('customer_phone', '9612388891')

        return_url = (
            f'http://localhost:14128/payment_response?order_id={quote(str(order_id))}'
            f'&status=success'
            f'&user_name={quote(str(customer_name))}'
            f'&user_mobile_number={quote(str(customer_phone))}'
            f'&total_amount={quote(str(data.get("total_amount", "")))}'
            f'&selected_numbers={quote(json.dumps(data.get("selected_numbers", [])))}'
            f'&selected_ranges={quote(json.dumps(data.get("selected_ranges", [])))}'
            f'&hou_heda_values={quote(json.dumps(data.get("hou_heda_values", {})))}'
            f'&hou_jeda_values={quote(json.dumps(data.get("hou_jeda_values", {})))}'
            f'&f_r_amounts={quote(json.dumps([0 if v is None else v for v in data.get("f_r_amounts", [])]))}'
            f'&s_r_amounts={quote(json.dumps([0 if v is None else v for v in data.get("s_r_amounts", [])]))}'
            f'&f_hou_amount={quote(str(data.get("f_hou_amount", "")))}'
            f'&s_hou_amount={quote(str(data.get("s_hou_amount", "")))}'
        )

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'x-client-id': CASHFREE_APP_ID,
            'x-client-secret': CASHFREE_SECRET_KEY,
            'x-api-version': '2023-08-01'
        }

        payload = {
            'order_id': order_id,
            'order_amount': order_amount,
            'order_currency': order_currency,
            'customer_details': {
                'customer_id': customer_id,
                'customer_name': customer_name,
                'customer_email': customer_email,
                'customer_phone': customer_phone
            },
            'order_meta': {
                'return_url': return_url
            }
        }

        logging.debug(f"Payload: {payload}")
        response = requests.post(CASHFREE_API_URL, json=payload, headers=headers)
        response_data = response.json()

        logging.debug(f"Response: {response_data}")

        if response.status_code == 200:
            payment_session_id = response_data.get('payment_session_id', '')
            if payment_session_id:
                return jsonify({
                    'order_id': order_id,
                    'payment_session_id': payment_session_id
                })
            else:
                return jsonify({'error': 'Payment session ID not found'}), 500
        else:
            return jsonify({'error': response_data.get('message', 'Unknown error occurred')}), response.status_code

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Exception occurred: {e}")
        return jsonify({'error': 'An error occurred', 'details': str(e)}), 500

@app.route('/initiate_payment', methods=['POST'])
def initiate_payment():
    data = request.json
    order_id = data.get('order_id')
    order_amount = data.get('order_amount')

    payment_url = "https://sandbox.cashfree.com/checkout"

    payload = {
        'order_id': order_id,
        'order_amount': order_amount,
        'order_currency': 'INR',
        'return_url': f'http://localhost:14128/payment_response?order_id={order_id}'
    }

    response = requests.post(payment_url, json=payload, headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-client-id': CASHFREE_APP_ID,
        'x-client-secret': CASHFREE_SECRET_KEY,
    })

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        return jsonify({'payment_url': data.get('payment_url')})
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Failed to initiate payment'}), response.status_code

@app.route('/payment_response', methods=['GET'])
def payment_response():
    data = request.args.to_dict()
    order_id = data.get('order_id')
    user_name = data.get('customer_name')
    user_mobile_number = data.get('customer_phone')

    # Verify the payment with Cashfree
    payment_verification_url = f'https://sandbox.cashfree.com/pg/orders/{order_id}'
    headers = {
        'x-client-id': CASHFREE_APP_ID,
        'x-client-secret': CASHFREE_SECRET_KEY,
    }

    verification_response = requests.get(payment_verification_url, headers=headers)
    verification_data = verification_response.json()

    if verification_response.status_code == 200 and verification_data.get('order_status') == 'PAID':
        # Payment is verified
        return jsonify({
            'message': 'Payment verified',
            'order_id': order_id,
            'status': 'success',
            'redirect_url': 'image_screen',
            'user_name': user_name, # Include userName
            'user_mobile_number': user_mobile_number # Include userMobileNumber
        })
    else:
        # Payment not verified
        return jsonify({
            'message': 'Payment verification failed',
            'order_id': order_id,
            'status': 'failed'
        })

@app.route('/payment_notification', methods=['POST'])
def payment_notification():
    data = request.form.to_dict()
    # Handle payment notification, usually updating the order status based on the notification.
    return jsonify({'message': 'Payment notification received', 'data': data})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
  # Turn off debug mode for production

Issue:
I noticed that some fields in my payload, specifically f_r_amounts, s_r_amounts, f_hou_amount, and s_hou_amount, contain None values, which likely causes the request to fail.
Error logs
 INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [03/Aug/2024 18:54:19] "OPTIONS /create_order HTTP/1.1" 200 -
DEBUG:root:Request data: {'order_id': '84f1206a-a0c6-4c15-a04c-bf2f260a0229', 'order_amount': '1905', 'customer_id': 'default_customer_id', 'customer_name': '7th SRB', 'customer_email': 'teerkhelo@gmail.com', 'customer_phone': '+917777777777', 'total_amount': '1905', 'selected_numbers': [25, 71], 'selected_ranges': ['1 H', '7 E', 'A P'], 'hou_heda_values': {'7 E': '350', '1 H': '500', 'A P': 
'50'}, 'hou_jeda_values': {'1 H': '400', 'A P': '100', '7 E': '400'}, 'f_r_amounts': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '10', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '40', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], 's_r_amounts': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '20', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '35', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], 'f_hou_amount': None, 's_hou_amount': None}
DEBUG:root:Payload: {'order_id': '84f1206a-a0c6-4c15-a04c-bf2f260a0229', 'order_amount': '1905', 'order_currency': 'INR', 'customer_details': {'customer_id': 
'default_customer_id', 'customer_name': '7th SRB', 'customer_email': 'teerkhelo@gmail.com', 'customer_phone': '+917777777777'}, 'order_meta': {'return_url': 'http://localhost:6950/payment_response?order_id=84f1206a-a0c6-4c15-a04c-bf2f260a0229&status=success&user_name=7th%20SRB&user_mobile_number=%2B917777777777&total_amount=1905&selected_numbers=%5B25%2C%2071%5D&selected_ranges=%5B%221%20H%22%2C%20%227%20E%22%2C%20%22A%20P%22%5D&hou_heda_values=%7B%227%20E%22%3A%20%22350%22%2C%20%221%20H%22%3A%20%22500%22%2C%20%22A%20P%22%3A%20%2250%22%7D&hou_jeda_values=%7B%221%20H%22%3A%20%22400%22%2C%20%22A%20P%22%3A%20%22100%22%2C%20%227%20E%22%3A%20%22400%22%7D&f_r_amounts=%5B0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%20%2210%22%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%20%2240%22%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%5D&s_r_amounts=%5B0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%20%2220%22%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%20%2235%22%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%5D&f_hou_amount=None&s_hou_amount=None'}}
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): sandbox.cashfree.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://sandbox.cashfree.com:443 "POST /pg/orders HTTP/11" 500 76
DEBUG:root:Response: {'message': 'api Request Failed', 'code': 'request_failed', 'type': 'api_error'}
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [03/Aug/2024 18:54:20] "POST /create_order HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Solution Attempt but not worked.
I tried replacing None values with 0 for lists and an empty string for individual fields before sending the request to Cashfree:
f_r_amounts = [0 if v is None else v for v in data.get("f_r_amounts", [])]
s_r_amounts = [0 if v is None else v for v in data.get("s_r_amounts", [])]
f_hou_amount = data.get("f_hou_amount", "")
s_hou_amount = data.get("s_hou_amount", "")

Flutter code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cashfree_pg_sdk/api/cferrorresponse/cferrorresponse.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cashfree_pg_sdk/api/cfpayment/cfwebcheckoutpayment.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cashfree_pg_sdk/api/cfpaymentgateway/cfpaymentgatewayservice.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cashfree_pg_sdk/api/cfsession/cfsession.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cashfree_pg_sdk/utils/cfenums.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cashfree_pg_sdk/utils/cfexceptions.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

class PaymentScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final double totalAmount;
  final List<int> selectedNumbers;
  final List<String> selectedRanges;
  final String? fHouAmount;
  final String? sHouAmount;
  final Map<String, String?> houHedaValues;
  final Map<String, String?> houJedaValues;
  final List<String?> fRAmounts;
  final List<String?> sRAmounts;
  final String userName;
  final String userMobileNumber;
  final BuildContext context;

  const PaymentScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.totalAmount,
    required this.selectedNumbers,
    required this.selectedRanges,
    required this.houHedaValues,
    required this.houJedaValues,
    required this.fRAmounts,
    required this.sRAmounts,
    this.fHouAmount,
    this.sHouAmount,
    required this.userName,
    required this.userMobileNumber,
    required this.context,
  });

  Future<void> createOrderAndInitiatePayment(BuildContext context) async {
    final orderId = Uuid().v4();
    final orderData = {
      "order_id": orderId,
      "order_amount": totalAmount.toString(),
      "customer_id": 'default_customer_id',
      "customer_name": userName,
      "customer_email": 'teerkhelo@gmail.com',
      "customer_phone": userMobileNumber,
      "total_amount": totalAmount.toString(),
      "selected_numbers": selectedNumbers,
      "selected_ranges": selectedRanges,
      "hou_heda_values": houHedaValues,
      "hou_jeda_values": houJedaValues,
      "f_r_amounts": fRAmounts,
      "s_r_amounts": sRAmounts,
      "f_hou_amount": fHouAmount,
      "s_hou_amount": sHouAmount,
    };

    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:5000/create_order'),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: json.encode(orderData),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
        final String paymentSessionId = responseData['payment_session_id'];

        if (paymentSessionId.isNotEmpty) {
          _createAndStartPaymentSession(orderId, paymentSessionId, context);
        } else {
          print('Error: Missing payment_session_id');
        }
      } else {
        print('Failed to create order: ${response.body}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
  }

  void _createAndStartPaymentSession(
      String orderId, String paymentSessionId, BuildContext context) {
    try {
      CFSession session = CFSessionBuilder()
          .setEnvironment(CFEnvironment.SANDBOX) //PRODUCTION/SANDBOX
          .setOrderId(orderId)
          .setPaymentSessionId(paymentSessionId)
          .build();

      var cfWebCheckoutBuilder =
          CFWebCheckoutPaymentBuilder().setSession(session);
      var cfWebCheckout = cfWebCheckoutBuilder.build();
      CFPaymentGatewayService().setCallback(
        (orderId) => onVerify(orderId, context),
        (errorResponse, orderId) => onError(errorResponse, orderId),
      );
      CFPaymentGatewayService().doPayment(cfWebCheckout);
    } on CFException catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }

  void onVerify(String orderId, BuildContext context) async {
    final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:5000/payment_response?order_id=$orderId'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      final String status = responseData['status'];
      final String redirectUrl = responseData['redirect_url'];

      if (status == 'success' && redirectUrl == 'image_screen') {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ImageScreen(
              status: 'PAYMENT SUCCESSFUL',
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        // Handle other statuses or errors
        print('Payment not successful');
      }
    } else {
      // Handle HTTP error
      print('Failed to verify payment');
    }
  }

  void onError(CFErrorResponse errorResponse, String orderId) {
    print("Error while making payment: ${errorResponse.getMessage()}");
    // Handle payment error
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String formattedDateTime = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a').format(now);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Token'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        // UI detials here. remeber to uncomment time imports
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        userName,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        userMobileNumber,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Opacity(
                  opacity: 0.5,
                  child: Text(
                    formattedDateTime,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      const Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Num',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                              // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'F/R',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                              // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'S/R',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      ...selectedNumbers.map((number) {
                        String? frAmount = fRAmounts[number];
                        String? srAmount = sRAmounts[number];
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(
                                    number.toString(),
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(
                                    (frAmount != null) ? '₹$frAmount' : '×',
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(
                                    (srAmount != null) ? '₹$srAmount' : '×',
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      }) //.toList(),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      ...selectedRanges.map((selectedHou) {
                        String? hedaAmount = houHedaValues[selectedHou];
                        String? jedaAmount = houJedaValues[selectedHou];
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(
                                    selectedHou,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(
                                    hedaAmount != null ? '₹$hedaAmount' : '×',
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(
                                    jedaAmount != null ? '₹$jedaAmount' : '×',
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      }) //.toList(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'Total Amount:',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            Text(
              '₹${totalAmount.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                createOrderAndInitiatePayment(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Pay Now'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String status;

  const ImageScreen({super.key, required this.status});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Payment Status'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          status, // Display the status text
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 24.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PaymentResponseHandler extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Uri uri = Uri.base;

    final String? status = uri.queryParameters['status'];
    final String? orderId = uri.queryParameters['order_id'];
    final String? userName = uri.queryParameters['user_name'];
    final String? userMobileNumber = uri.queryParameters['user_mobile_number'];
    final String? totalAmount = uri.queryParameters['total_amount'];
    final String? selectedNumbers = uri.queryParameters['selected_numbers'];
    final String? selectedRanges = uri.queryParameters['selected_ranges'];
    final String? houHedaValues = uri.queryParameters['hou_heda_values'];
    final String? houJedaValues = uri.queryParameters['hou_jeda_values'];
    final String? fRAmounts = uri.queryParameters['f_r_amounts'];
    final String? sRAmounts = uri.queryParameters['s_r_amounts'];
    final String? fHouAmount = uri.queryParameters['f_hou_amount'];
    final String? sHouAmount = uri.queryParameters['s_hou_amount'];

    if (status == 'success') {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ImageScreen(
              status:
                  'PAYMENT SUCCESSFUL\nOrder ID: $orderId\nUser: $userName\nPhone: $userMobileNumber\nTotal Amount: $totalAmount\nSelected Numbers: $selectedNumbers\nSelected Ranges: $selectedRanges\nHou Heda Values: $houHedaValues\nHou Jeda Values: $houJedaValues\nF R Amounts: $fRAmounts\nS R Amounts: $sRAmounts\nF Hou Amount: $fHouAmount\nS Hou Amount: $sHouAmount',
            ),
          ),
        );
      });

      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Payment failed or invalid. Order ID: $orderId',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}


The return_url is too long. Please use a smaller one and try
You can try with this for now -> https://www.cashfree.com/devstudio/preview/pg/web/checkout?order_id={order_id}
